# How to implement async update method for SqlDataAdapter?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, ado.net, dataadapter, sqldataadapter

I want to create an extension method that update the changed data in async method using SqlDataAdapter

I've created simple extension but it's not functioning fast.

```
    public static Task<int> UpdateAsync (this SqlDataAdapter adapter,DataTable changedData)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {

            return adapter.Update(changedData); 

        },CancellationToken.None,TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,TaskScheduler.Default);
    }
```

I want to update every row in the changed rows in a parallel

I tried to do something like that :

```
    public static async Task<int> UpdateAsync(this SqlDataAdapter adapter, DataTable changedData)
    {
        if (adapter == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(adapter));
        if (changedData == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(changedData));
        if (changedData.Rows.Count == 0) return default;

        SqlConnection connection = adapter.SelectCommand.Connection;

        if (!connection.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Open))
            await connection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        // deleted rows
        bool isThereDeletedRows = changedData.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Any(row => row.RowState.Equals(DataRowState.Deleted));

        var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();

        if (isThereDeletedRows)
        {
             Task<int> task= adapter.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
             tasks.Add(task);
        }

        // updated rows 
        bool isThereModifiedRows = changedData.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Any(row => row.RowState.Equals(DataRowState.Modified));
        if (isThereModifiedRows)
        {
             Task<int> task= adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
             tasks.Add(task);
        }

        // new added rows 
        bool isThereAddedRows = changedData.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Any(row => row.RowState.Equals(DataRowState.Added));
        if (isThereAddedRows)
        {
            Task<int> task= adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
             tasks.Add(task);
        }

        int[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);


        if (connection.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Open) ) connection.Close();

        return results.Sum();

    }
```

but I don't know who to assign the commands parameters dynamically like the normal Update method

Now
I did something like this

```
 public static async Task<int> UpdateAsync(this SqlDataAdapter adapter, 
 DataTable changedData)
    {
        if (adapter == null) throw new 
ArgumentNullException(nameof(adapter));
        if (changedData == null) throw new 
 ArgumentNullException(nameof(changedData));
        if (changedData.Rows.Count == 0) return default;

        SqlConnection connection = adapter.SelectCommand.Connection;

        if (!connection.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Open))
            await connection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();

        // deleted rows
        Task<int> deleteTask= DeleteRowsTask(adapter, changedData);
        tasks.Add(deleteTask);

        // updated rows 
        Task<int> modifyTask= ModifyRowsTask(adapter, changedData);
        tasks.Add(modifyTask);

        // new added rows 
        Task<int> addTask= AddRowsTask(adapter, changedData);
        tasks.Add(addTask);


        int[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (connection.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Open)) 
            connection.Close();

        return results.Sum();
    }

    private static async Task<int> AddRowsTask(SqlDataAdapter adapter, DataTable changedData)
    {

        var result = 0;
        List<DataRow> addedRows = changedData.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Where(row => row.RowState.Equals(DataRowState.Added)).ToList();
        if (addedRows.Count == 0) return result;

        foreach (DataRow row in addedRows)
        {
            AssignCommandParameters(adapter.InsertCommand, row);

            Task<int> task = adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

            result += await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static void AssignCommandParameters(SqlCommand command, DataRow row)
    {
        foreach (SqlParameter parameter in command.Parameters) 
            parameter.Value = row[parameter.SourceColumn];
    }

    private static async Task<int> DeleteRowsTask(SqlDataAdapter adapter, DataTable changedData)
    {
        List<DataRow> deletedRows = changedData.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Where(row => row.RowState.Equals(DataRowState.Deleted)).ToList();

        var result = 0;

        if (deletedRows.Count == 0) return result;

        foreach (DataRow row in deletedRows)
        {
            AssignCommandParameters(adapter.DeleteCommand, row);

            Task<int> task = adapter.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            result += await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static async Task<int> ModifyRowsTask(SqlDataAdapter adapter, DataTable changedData)
    {
        var result = 0;
        List<DataRow> modifiedRows = changedData.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Where(row => row.RowState.Equals(DataRowState.Modified)).ToList();
        if (modifiedRows.Count == 0) return result;


        foreach (DataRow row in modifiedRows)
        {
            AssignCommandParameters(adapter.UpdateCommand, row);

            Task<int> task = adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

            result += await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I did this for output parameters :

```
    private static void AssignOutputParameters(SqlCommand command, DataRow row)
    {
        foreach (SqlParameter parameter in command.Parameters)
        {
            if (parameter.Direction == ParameterDirection.Output || parameter.Direction == ParameterDirection.InputOutput)
            {
                row[parameter.SourceColumn] = parameter.Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't understand what are you meaning ?! but my problem is that the method I've created is not actually a real improvement

Comment: You are still using an entire `DataTable`. You have only wrapped the process inside a task. You should consider profiling the update and perhaps create batch-updates.

Comment: Can you show me how ?

Comment: You should try that yourself first and then ask a question where you got stuck. Hint: Start by iterating the rows in your `DataTable` and save them each separately. Don't use a Task (yet). Take this step-by-step.

Comment: I modified my question. I wrote that method but I'm not sure if this is the correct implementation. and if it will work as normal Update method because I'm mapping some output parameters